# Exception occurs while running web application in glassfish application server 3.1.2.2 version

Tags: jsp, web-applications, glassfish-3

I have developed a web application. It's successfully deployed in Glassfish server   3.1.2.2, but while executing it's giving an exception like:

```
HTTP Status 500 -
descriptionThe server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request. 
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6033: Error in Javac compilation for JSP    
PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 100 in the jsp file: /inOrganicLeftOutViewDetails.jsp 
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6033: Error in Javac compilation for JSP  
PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 100 in the jsp file: /inOrganicLeftOutViewDetails.jsp  
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:  
cannot find symbol  
  symbol:   class lang  
  location: package java  
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:  
cannot find symbol  
  symbol:   variable _jspx_temp0    
  location: class org.apache.jsp.inOrganicLeftOutViewDetails_jsp
```

Comment: Are you inserting any JSP page using `<jsp:include>` ?

Comment: maybe you are missing some imports in the jsp file. <%@page import="package.Class" %> but perhaps post the code also

Comment: you must paste your JSP page here. Especially line 100